# Check multiple URL in an array if they exist but only if first URL in array does not exist

Tags: php

**I'm trying to create a PHP script that checks if a URL exists.
I got multiple URLs in an array I would like to check but only if the first URL in the array $sources does not exist and I'm not sure how i can do this.**

The below PHP code is how "I think" and how I would like it to be but it's just an example and it is most likely not the correct way to do it.

PHP code:

```
<?php
// an array that contains all the URL sources we can use
$sources = array("source-1.com/img.png", "source-2.com/img.png", "source-3.com/img.png",    "source-4.com/img.png");

foreach($sources as $source) {

 $source_headers = @get_headers($source);

 if($source_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
// First source in the array did not work execute code to try next URL in the array
 }
 else {
// Ok we got a working source, Lets use it.
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks alright to me. I have done a similar task with nearly identical code and it worked. As far as it being the right thing to do, I think it is. You're not really asking your "question" very clearly. Consider modifying it to be more specific.